# ORACLE SQL - Ordenar por soma

Tags: sql, oracle

Preciso fazer um relatório e não estou conseguindo ordenar ele como desejo, eu quero selecionar o débito de clientes entre 60 e 120 dias e ordenar pelo total. O código está assim:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(cod_fat_cli) "Total",
  nom_cad_cli "Nome",
  end_cad_cli "Endereço"
FROM 
  cadastro_cliente
WHERE 
  --Seleciona as faturas em aberto
  cod_fat_cli = 'AB' 
  --Seleciona as faturas vencidas entre 60 e 120 dias
  AND venc_fat_cli BETWEEN trunc(sysdate -120) AND trunc(sysdate - 60)
```

#### Dúvida

Se eu ordeno por cod_fat_cli retorna ordenando as maiores faturas, mas eu preciso das maiores somas.

Comment: Acho que a seu SQL está errado o campo `` cod_fat_cli`` está para ser somado e está como filtro de string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o SQL que você passou está incompleto.
Então no exemplo abaixo, criei uma nova coluna com o "valor" da fatura do cliente, com o nome `vlr_fat_cli`.

#### SQL

```
SELECT 
  SUM(vlr_fat_cli) "Total",
  nom_cad_cli "Nome"  
FROM 
  cadastro_cliente
WHERE 
  --Seleciona as faturas em aberto
  cod_fat_cli = 'AB' 
  --Seleciona as faturas vencidas entre 60 e 120 dias
  AND venc_fat_cli BETWEEN trunc(sysdate -120) AND trunc(sysdate - 60)
group by
  nom_cad_cli
order by
  1 desc
```

#### Explicação

Depois do comando `order by` para a ordenação, você pode utilizar o número da coluna do campo que você deseja ordenar, como eu fiz acima. Mas tome cuidado, ao editar o SQL e colocar mais campos você tem que lembrar de ajustar o `order by`.

Você também poderia fazer no lugar do `1 desc` fazer `SUM(vlr_fat_cli) desc` que geraria o resultado esperado e não teria problemas ao adicionar novos campos.

#### Exemplo prático

Criei o exemplo prático aqui http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4359c/9

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado